# Strcat() throws acces violation exception. Why?

Tags: c

```
int verify(char filename[], int filenameLength) // If f.ex. filename is "x.txt" then filenameLength is 5
{
    char* filenameCorrect = malloc(sizeof(char) * (filenameLength + 9));
    filenameCorrect = "correct_";
    strcat(filenameCorrect, filename);

    ...
}
```

Everytime i run this i get this exception: "Access violation writing location".

Comment: `filenameCorrect = "correct_";` --> `strcpy(filenameCorrect, "correct_");`

Comment: As a matter of safety, you should be checking the result of `malloc` to see if you get `NULL` back as an  error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filenameCorrect` is a pointer, not a variable that holds the characters rather a pointer to some area in memory that was assigned to hold the characters. In the second line you are reassigning `filenameCorrect` to point to a string that is compiled as part of the code and thus cannot be changed hence the error.

What you are looking for is to copy the string `"correct_"` to the allocated area in memory.  So use:

```
strcpy(filenameCorrect, "correct_");
```

then you can safely use `strcat`.